# How can I get separate plots for each columns(A,B,C,D) vs date side by side using python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph-visualization

I have similar data as below in my pandas dataframe.

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 10000 | 1700 | 1457 | 327 |
| 02-01-2022 | 17000 | 3000 | 1245 | 526 |
| 03-01-2022 | 16000 | 2624 | 1478 | 632 |
| 04-01-2022 | 10138 | 1745 | 1325 | 800 |
| 05-01-2022 | 4761 | 1789 | 1475 | 952 |
| 06-01-2022 | 5000 | 1874 | 1423 | 1105 |
| 07-01-2022 | 3000 | 1965 | 1421 | 895 |
| 08-01-2022 | 4000 | 1847 | 1420 | 1410 |
| 09-01-2022 | 3001 | 1654 | 1418 | 564 |
| 10-01-2022 | 3002 | 1754 | 1417 | 1715 |
| 11-01-2022 | 3003 | 1598 | 1415 | 564 |
| 12-01-2022 | 3004 | 1515 | 1414 | 2020 |
| 13-01-2022 | 3005 | 1433 | 1412 | 564 |
| 14-01-2022 | 3006 | 1350 | 1411 | 2325 |
| 15-01-2022 | 3007 | 1268 | 1409 | 456 |

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d94EK.png)

How can I get separate plots side by side as date vs A, Date vs B, Date Vs C and so on, using python?

I am still learning, new to python and data visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using pandas plot with `subplots` equal to True, and `layout` with (row, column) tuple:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df.set_index('Date').plot(subplots=True, layout=(1,4), figsize=(15,7))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer. This is working for 4 columns(plots) side by side. But when I try this for more than 30 columns(plots) it looks congested as all the plots are coming in same row. Is there a way I can make it readable, move plots to next row?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate row and columns a bases on the number of columns in your dataframe and know how many plots you want on one line.

Comment: Something like (np.ceil(df.shape[1] / 4), 4) assumming your want four charts per line.